# How to import data into a user when another user with same data exists

Tags: database, oracle11g

I am facing ORA-39151 error while trying to import data into a user when there is another user with same tables

```
ORA-39151: Table "HR"."EMPLOYEES" exists. All dependent metadata and data will be skipped due to table_exists_action of skip
```

How to make import all the tables into a different user when another user exists with same data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`impdp user/password DUMPFILE=file_name directory=dir LOGFILE=test.log REMAP_SCHEMA=USERA:USERB TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=APPEND`

USER A is the existing user USER B is the new user